# How to display my facebook page in my app

Tags: android-studio

I know how to get particular data like posts in my app.But, I want to display my entire facebook page in my app like this :

[image]

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Just add facebook URL in webview

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using WebView.

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"  
    android:layout_width="match_parent"  
    android:layout_height="match_parent"  
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >  


        <WebView  
            android:id="@+id/webView1"  
            android:layout_width="match_parent"  
            android:layout_height="match_parent"  
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"  
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"  
            android:layout_marginTop="42dp" />  

    </RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.webview;  

import android.os.Bundle;  
import android.app.Activity;  
import android.view.Menu;  
import android.webkit.WebView;  

public class MainActivity extends Activity {  

    @Override  
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  

        WebView mywebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);  
        mywebview.loadUrl("http://www.facebook.com/");  

       }  

}
```